# How to SSH into an AWS EC2 instance which does not have a public DNS address

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS and I've just created a EC2 instance running inside a VPC that I created from scratch. I'm using the console to do all this. My question is, how to access the EC2 instance I just created via ssh?

Looking at the details for the instance I notice it does not have a public DNS address, but it does have a public IP and private IP and DNS address:

```
Public DNS (IPv4) -
IPv4 Public IP 52.xx.xxx.xx
Private DNS ip-192-168-0-xxx.us-west-1.compute.internal
Private IPs 192.168.0.xxx
```

Notice the Public DNS is blank. How can I ssh into this box? Normally I think you need the public DNS address.

Comment: By using the IP address given?

Comment: This is probably a question you should be asking at [sf], since it's not a programming questin.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I tried connecting via ip address but the server address doesn't seem to resolve.

Comment: Did you create the instance in the private subnet of the VPC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can SSH to an instance via its **Public IP Address** or its **Public DNS**. This is because the Public DNS will resolve to the Public IP address, so it's the same thing.

The reason there is no DNS name appearing is that you created a new Amazon VPC and there is a VPC setting called **DNS Hostnames**.

[image: Edit DNS Hostnames]

If this option is set to `Yes`, then a DNS name will be automatically allocated to Amazon EC2 instances in the VPC, such as: `ec2-154-253-52-151.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

Other requirements to be able to SSH into the instance are:

- It is a **Linux instance** (Windows does not have an ssh server by default)
- It is in a **Public Subnet** (defined as a subnet that has a Route Table entry to an Internet Gateway)
- The **Security Group** permits the connection on port 22 for your incoming IP address
- Traffic not blocked by the **Network Access Control List** (which is fully open by default)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a public DNS for SSH
You can do that with the IP,  provided the instance resides in a public subnet

If the instance is in private subnet then you need a bastion Host that is in public subnet. And you can use that bastion host to login to your instance in private subnet